# PHP JSON Array encoding for use with JSOUP Android

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to build a catalog database that will interact with an Android Application for viewing when one scans a barcode. The app should ask the MySQL database and query for the various items associated with the part. Code is here for the MySQL part of it:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['catalog'])) {
    require("connect_to_mysql.php");
    header("content-type: application/json");

    $tables_result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES") or die(mysql_error());

    while ($table = mysql_fetch_row($tables_result)) {
        $query_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table[0]." WHERE catalog = '".$_POST['catalog']."'") or die(mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($query_results) > 0) {
            $fields = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table[0]);

            while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($fields)) {
                $names[] = $res[0];
            }

            $comments = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT table_comment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name='".$table[0]."'")) or die(mysql_error());

            while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query_results)){
                $rows["part"] = $comments[0];
                $rows["fields"] = $names;
                for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($query_results); $i++){
                    $rows[$names[$i]] = $array[$i];
                }
                echo json_encode($rows);
            }
        }
    }
    mysql_free_result($tables_result); 
}
if(!isset($_POST['submit']) || !isset($_POST['catalog'])) {
    echo "
    <form method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='catalog' />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' />
    </form>
    ";
}
?>
```

However, for instance, a result of this would be:

```
{"part":"Lospa Tibial Baseplate","fields":["catalog","size"],"catalog":"01.10.50B","size":"11"}
```

I am using JSOUP on the Android Client Side and it has the function of returning a JSONArray. A JSONArray from when I've used this in the past looks like this (the part of the JSON I am having a problem with is the "field" object):

```
{"part":"Lospa Tibial Baseplate","fields":{["catalog","size"]},"catalog":"01.10.50B","size":"11"}
```

I've tried straight up encoding the array before encoding the fields array but that didn't work out and returned a bunch of slashes and useless stuff:

```
{"part":"Lospa Tibial Baseplate","fields":"[\"catalog\",\"size\"]","catalog":"01.10.50B","size":"11"}
```

What's the best way I should go about this? I would rather not just hard-code the two brackets into there, but if that is the last option, please show me how to do that because I can't just `$rows["fields"] = "{".$names."}";`

Comment: its always a bad idea trying to encode each item inside the loop, always build the complete array structure first in PHP, then after you're done with it, then you encode

Comment: JSOUP really prefers `"fields":{["catalog","size"]}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is my code below. I basically had to make an array of encoded JSON objects. Thanks to Kim for pointing in the right direction. I also did some changes the the function, but that doesn't have an impact on the JSON Part of it.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['catalog'])) {
    require("connect_to_mysql.php");
    header("content-type: application/json");

$tables_result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES") or die(mysql_error());
while ($table = mysql_fetch_row($tables_result)) {
    $query_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table[0]." WHERE catalog = '".$_POST['catalog']."'") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($query_results) > 0) {


        $comments = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT table_comment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name='".$table[0]."'")) or die(mysql_error());
        $columns_sql = mysql_query("SELECT COLUMN_COMMENT FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '".$table[0]."'") or die(mysql_error());
        $rows["validity"] = true;
        $rows["part"] = $comments[0];

        while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($columns_sql)) {
            $names[] = $res[0];
        }
        $rows["fields_count"] = count($names);

        while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query_results)){

            for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($query_results); $i++){
                $values[] = array($names[$i] => $array[$i]);
            }
        }
        $rows["fields"] = $values;
        echo json_encode($rows);
        exit();
    }
}
echo '{"validity":false}';
mysql_free_result($tables_result); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the structure after it has finished building:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['catalog'])) {
    require("connect_to_mysql.php");
    header("content-type: application/json");

    $tables_result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES") or die(mysql_error());

    while ($table = mysql_fetch_row($tables_result)) {
        $query_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table[0]." WHERE catalog = '".$_POST['catalog']."'") or die(mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($query_results) > 0) {
            $fields = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table[0]);

            while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($fields)) {
                $names[] = $res[0];
            }

            $comments = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT table_comment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name='".$table[0]."'")) or die(mysql_error());

            while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query_results)){
                $rows["part"] = $comments[0];
                $rows["fields"] = $names;
                for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($query_results); $i++){
                    $rows[$names[$i]] = $array[$i];
                }
            }

            // JSON encode at the end
            echo json_encode($rows);
        }
    }
    mysql_free_result($tables_result); 
}
```

This is invalid JSON, by the way:

```
{"fields":{["catalog","size"]},"catalog":"01.10.50B","size":"11"}
```

Should be more like this if `fields` must be an object.

```
{"fields":{"key":["catalog","size"]},"catalog":"01.10.50B","size":"11"}
```

So it's better to check if your JSOUP parsing is setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The field structure is not correct...

This is why I use the [Simple JSON for PHP](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP) library! It allows to avoid to hardcode our JSON.

Using `$Json->addContent(new arrayJson("fields",$values));` will set the field `fields` of your json equals to your values. It should look like this :

```
<?php
include('includes/json.php');

$Json = new json();
if(isset($_POST['catalog'])) {
    require("connect_to_mysql.php");
    header("content-type: application/json");

$tables_result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES") or die(mysql_error());
while ($table = mysql_fetch_row($tables_result)) {
    $query_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table[0]." WHERE catalog = '".$_POST['catalog']."'") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($query_results) > 0) {

        $comments = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT table_comment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name='".$table[0]."'")) or die(mysql_error());
        $columns_sql = mysql_query("SELECT COLUMN_COMMENT FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '".$table[0]."'") or die(mysql_error());

        $Json->addContent(new propertyJson('status', '200'));
        $Json->addContent(new propertyJson('validity', true));
        $Json->addContent(new propertyJson('part', $comments[0]));

        while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($columns_sql)) {
            $names[] = $res[0];
        }
        $Json->addContent(new propertyJson('count', count($names))); = 

        while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query_results)){

            for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($query_results); $i++){
                $values[] = array($names[$i] => $array[$i]);
            }
        }

        $Json->addContent(new arrayJson("fields",$values));
        json_send($Json);
        exit();
    }
}
$Json->addContent(new propertyJson('status', '200'));
$Json->addContent(new propertyJson('message', 'Validity failed'));
json_send($Json);
mysql_free_result($tables_result); 
}
?>
```